# Running a lua program from a text file

Tags: lua

I've just started learning Lua, and I'm trying to get the native Lua interpreter to run a program that has been saved to a `.txt` file. I'm running Windows Vista with Lua 5.1.4.

Perhaps I'm missing something, but the only thing my book (*Programming in Lua*) says is that *all you have to do to run your program is to call the interpreter with the name of the text file that contains your program*. Then it gives this supposedly handy piece of code:

```
% lua filename.lua
```

Which I can't get to work in cmd or in the Lua interpreter. Further research I've done indicates that I might need to use a

```
dofile("filename.lua")
```

command, but I'm not sure how to do this. Specifically, what information do I need to put in the argument? Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a different editor, other than notepad. Try [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [vim](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim73_46.exe). The file name needs to literally be "filename.lua", notepad will append a ".txt" onto the end of that like "filename.lua.txt"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. notepad++ at the very least is a much better editor!

Answer (score 7):

You need to download a Win32 binary (see [lua-5.2.1_Win32_bin.zip or lua-5.2.1_Win64_bin.zip here](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html)). Unzip this somewhere. How to run your script, in order of easiness and inverse order or common procedure:

1. Drag your script onto the Lua.exe using the Windows file Explorer.
2. a. Move your script to the same folder as Lua.exe
   b. Shift right-click on that folder and select `Open Command Window Here`.
   c. Type `lua filename.lua` and press Enter.
3. Add the directory containing Lua.exe to your [system PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#0), then do steps 2a and 2b on the folder containing your script.
4. Integrate Lua.exe with your editor in some way (how you do this depends on your editor).

Comment: Okay, just trying to understand: is the Win32 binary is Lua itself or something else? Thank you for the steps and various options, but I can only get 2 to work. 1 only brings up the interpreter for a split second and then it closes. And I don't understand 3 enough to do it, nor will it fit my purposes right now. Is there any information you can give as far as why option 1 isn't working, or how to integrate Lua with *Notepad*, *Notepad++*, or *SciTE*? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Lua is a programming language. It's used in all manner of applications. The `lua.exe` in the zip file I linked is a very simple Windows command line interpreter for Lua, a no frills way of running Lua code. #1 is running your script, but as soon as the script exits, Lua.exe exits and the window goes away. If you want it to stick around, add the line `io.read()` to the end of your script, which will force it to wait until you press ENTER to exit. Try the script `print('Hello, World!') io.read()`.

Comment: Bingo! I got that interpreter when I installed the batteries included version of Lua. ;) With the io.read() script is works perfectly. For future reference, is there also I way to call the file open from inside the interpreter also?

Comment: @rocksrollsrules From the interpreter, you can use `dofile(filename)` function that you've already found.