# Changing the Lua command in CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, lua, environment-variables

I've just added Lua to my enviroment variables, but now, every time I need to run a lua command, I have to write `lua52 main.lua`. My question is, is there a way to change that command so that I can write `lua main.lua` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding lua.exe to my system path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419822/adding-lua-exe-to-my-system-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can rename `lua52.exe` into `lua.exe`.